# SVG in QML not showing on Android

Tags: android, qt, svg, qml

I have a Qt project. In my QML I include an svg image.

```
   Image {
    id: logo
    width: 90
    height: 25
    source: "logoHorizontalWhite.svg"
    y:25
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
}
```

I added XML and svg support in my .pro file

```
    QT += qml quick widgets svg xml
```

on iOS and Desktop it shows up correctly, on Android I get the error:

W/EGL_emulation(13992): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer(13992): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4a10520, error=EGL_SUCCESS
D/Qt      (13992): (null):0 ((null)): FT_New_Face failed with index 0 : 90
W/Qt      (13992): qrc:/LoginForm.qml:21 ((null)): qrc:/LoginForm.qml:21:5: QML Image: Invalid image data: qrc:/logoHorizontalWhite.svg
W/EGL_emulation(13992): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer(13992): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4a10520, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Any ideas what could cause this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A restart of the simulator solved it.